# Set interval for X and Y QwtPlotZoneItem

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I need to plot a region on a graph using the `QwtPlotZoneItem` class. I need to set different intervals for both X and Y axes, how can I do that?

The orientation of my `QwtPlotZoneItem` is **vertical**, so based on the documentation, if I set the interval it will by applied to the X axis only.

> "For a horizontal zone the interval is related to the y axis, for a
>   vertical zone it is related to the x axis."

My constructor sets:

```
setOrientation( Qt::Vertical );
setInterval( initDate, endDate );
```

Basically, what I need is to create multiple rectangles on my graph that represents the regions, for example:

[image]

Qt 5.3.2

Qwt 6.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use an incorrect class for my purposes. I found a **note** in the [documentation](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_zone_item.html#details):

> "For displaying an area that is bounded for x and y coordinates use
>   QwtPlotShapeItem"

The **QwtPlotShapeItem** class does exactly what I need.

I need basically to set the brush and create the rectangle, for example:

```
QwtPlotShapeItem *shapeItem = new QwtPlotShapeItem();

shapeItem->setBrush(QColor(255,255,255, 0));
shapeItem->setPen(QColor(Qt::transparent), 0.0, Qt::SolidLine);

// TopLeft - BottomRight
QRect myRect(QPoint(startDate, yUpperPos), QPoint(endDate, yLowerPos));
shapeItem->setRect( QRectF(myRect) );

shapeItem->attach(myQwtPlot);
myQwtPlot->replot();
```